# CanActivate in Angular 2 return undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frameworks, canactivate

I need that canActivate do not skip further until json loads, for this I put a check if canActivate is not undefined, it returned false, but in the console it outputs that canActivate is passed and with the value undefined. What I'm doing is wrong, I'll be grateful for help, thanks.

My `http-data.service`

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
export class HttpService implements CanActivate{
    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    dataModules = this.getDataModules();
    dataPresets = this.getDataPresets();
    dataModuleItems = this.getDataModuleItems();
    data: any[];

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<boolean> | boolean {
            if (this.getDataModules !== undefined) {
                console.log('canActivate');
                console.log(this.getDataModules());
                return true;
            } else return false;
    }

    getDataOrganizations(): Observable<any[]>{
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3010/data')
            .map((resp:Response)=>{
                let dataOrganizations = resp.json().organization;
                return dataOrganizations;
            });
    }

    loadDataModules(): Observable<any[]> {      
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3010/data')
            .map((resp: Response)=> {
                let dataModules = resp.json().modules;
                return dataModules;
            });
    }

    loadDataPresets(): Observable<any[]> {      
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3010/data')
            .map((resp: Response)=> {
                let dataPresets = resp.json().presets;
                return dataPresets;
            });
    }

    loadDataModuleItems(): Observable<any[]> {      
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3010/data')
            .map((resp: Response)=> {
                let dataModuleItems = resp.json().module_items;
                return dataModuleItems;
            });
    }

    loadData() {
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3010/data')
            .map((resp: Response)=> {
                let data = resp.json();
                return data;
            });
    }

    getDataModules(): any[] {
        this.loadDataModules().subscribe(((modules)=>{this.dataModules = modules; console.log('в http modules');console.log(this.dataModules);}));
        return this.dataModules;
    }


    getDataPresets(): any[] {
        this.loadDataPresets().subscribe(((presets)=>{this.dataPresets = presets; console.log(this.dataPresets);}));
        return this.dataPresets;
    }


    getDataModuleItems(): any[] {
        this.loadDataModuleItems().subscribe(((moduleItems)=>{this.dataModuleItems = moduleItems; console.log(this.dataModuleItems);}));
        return this.dataModuleItems;
    }
}
```

[image: canActivate: undefined[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U64D.png)

[image]

Comment: check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until you subscribe to the response your data will be `undefined`

```
 getDataOrganizations(): Observable<any[]>{
    let dataOrganizations :any[]
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:3010/data')
            .map(response => response.json().organization)
            .subscribe(data =>  {       
                dataOrganizations = data;
                return dataOrganizations; 
        });
    }
```

Now you will get the object

Comment: And the map() is needed?

Comment: was this helpful or need more help?

Comment: Thank you. Now it issues a subscriber object. And how can you get data out of it?

Comment: please see my updated code. let me know if you face any concerns